# Characters in string within post are being auto escaped

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am sending tokens via a POST request, but when I see them on the server it doesn't match up with what was sent.

`"U2FsdGVkX1+pxBHFdSU4NiSIOdR2GCCBr/WF7AOSF5zQjRqjSoTeOKR0Dzwm\nNT+g\n"`  <-- Original
`"U2FsdGVkX1+pxBHFdSU4NiSIOdR2GCCBr/WF7AOSF5zQjRqjSoTeOKR0Dzwm\\nNT+g\\n"` <-- Result

Notice that the \n has been replaced with \\n.  When I do the token lookup verification, of course, no result is found because the string I'm looking for is not the proper string anymore!

I'm not sure why this string is being auto changed like this or quite how to correct it.  I'm just accessing this through the standard params like so.

`token.verify(params["token"])`

> EDIT for further clarity

I'm viewing this from the terminal using the debugger gem. I have autoeval enabled and display with `params["token"]` without p or puts. I am not trying to create newline characters with \n. The literal `\n` is an actual part of the string that is received in the post. I randomly generate a token using a hashing and encryption library and the strings sometimes end up with these characters in them.  If I run `token.verify(params["token"])` from the debugger terminal I get nil back from the database as there is no match due to the extra backslash characters being added into the string.

If I directly run `token.verify("U2FsdGVkX1+pxBHFdSU4NiSIOdR2GCCBr/WF7AOSF5zQjRqjSoTeOKR0Dzwm\nNT+g\n")` from the debugger terminal I get the correct record back from the database. This leaves me thinking that either Rack or Sinatra is auto escaping the "special" characters in the string before I get a chance to even touch it.

Comment: The token is being escaped, can you update question with the code that sends the `post` request?

Comment: It is not being escaped sending it in as far as I can tell.  I'm currently just using a post request via curl to test as I'm building out my API.  `curl --data "token=U2FsdGVkX1+pxBHFdSU4NiSIOdR2GCCBr/WF7AOSF5zQjRqjSoTeOKR0Dzwm\nNT+g\n" http://localhost:4567/auth/verify_token`

Comment: How are you viewing the result? If you are doing something like `p params["token"]` then Ruby will escape the ``\`` by doubling them when displaying the string, but the “real” string will only have single characters. Also note than curl will be sending `\n` as literals, _not_ as a newline character, so you might need to change how you are using curl (it’s not clear if you mean to send newlines or literal `\n`).

Comment: Matt, I've added additional information above to try and clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has something to with the way Ruby is handling special characters. From irb you can see this with a quick check like this.

```
"\\n" == '\n'
```

Unexpectedly; at least to me, this returns true as they are treated the same.  Rather than trying to deal with special characters coming across the wire I ended up just base 64 encoding everything.

Comment: In Ruby, strings in single quotes don't have escape sequences applied. "\n" is a newline, '\n' is a backslash followed by an n, which happens to be the same as "\\n".